# Check if username already exists in database (Python + Pymongo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to make a registration module to use in a larger login/authentication program and I need to make a function that can check if a username already exists in a collection.

I haven't tried much more than this, this is my first real programming project and I'm stuck on this part. I realize I could use in-line dictionary databases, but I want to learn how to integrate 3rd party databases with my programming.
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
loginDB = client["loginDB"]
userCol = loginDB["userCol"]

##Username##
print('Choose A Unique Username')
time.sleep(1.2)
unameInput = input("Enter Username: ")
unameList = {'Username': unameInput}
unameQuery = {}
unameQuery2 = userCol.find_one({'Username.Username': {'$gt': 'a'}})

if unameInput != unameQuery2:
    print('Name is Available | Accepted!')
    allList = {'Username': unameList}
    userCol.insert_one(allList)
else:
    print('Sorry, Please Try Again.')`
```

The expected result is to search the database for everything that starts with the letter "a", forward. If the input (unameInput) does not equal anything in the query result (unameQuery2), then print "Username is available". If anything in the query matches the input, then print "Please try again", however, it's accepting everything that is input and exiting the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `find_one()` to find one entry in Username and then checking if `unameInput` is equal to it. If it's not an exact match, it will execute the code for name is available.
Try find() instead as this will iterate over all the documents in the collection.

```
unameQuery2 = userCol.find() 
if unameInput not in unameQuery2: 
    # do something
```

Comment: This is the output: 

  File "C:/Users/ROOT/Desktop/python/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    unameQuery2 = userCol.all()
  File "C:\Users\ROOT\Desktop\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 3321, in __call__
    self.__name.split(".")[-1])
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'all' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

Comment: I don't think I'm able to use "all" as a pymongo query

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was putting dictionaries inside of dictionaries inside of documents, as well as not iterating "allList".